# Operator<< for std::string

Tags: c++, operators

I define the operator<< for std::string objects:

```
std::string & operator<< (std::string & left, std::string & right){
    return left += right;
}
```

Then I use it:

```
        std::string t1("t1"), t2("t2"), t3;
        t3 = t2 << t1;
```

And get from a compiler:

```
t.cpp: In function 'int main()':
t.cpp:44:28: error: no matching function for call to 'operator<<(std::string&, std::string&)'
t.cpp:44:28: note: candidates are:
In file included from d:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/iostream:40:0,
                 from connection.h:10,
                 from login.cpp:1:
d:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/ostream:600:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Tp> std::basic_ostream<_CharT
, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&)
d:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/ostream:600:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
t.cpp:44:28: note:   'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>'
In file included from d:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/iostream:40:0,
```

Why talks it about ostream and does not talk about string? I.e. why it does not take in account my definition of the operator<< ?

Thanks.

Update. For those who is able just to say "why do you create operator<< for strings?" and is not able to say any helpful things:

```
std::string & operator<< (std::string & left, const int num){
    return left += std::to_string(num);
}

 std::string t3;
 t3 << 3 << 5;
 std::cout << t3 << std::endl;
```

And log:

```
t.cpp: In function 'int main()':
t.cpp:45:12: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 't3 << 3'
t.cpp:45:12: note: candidates are:
In file included from d:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/iostream:40:0,
                 from connection.h:10,
                 from login.cpp:1:
d:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/ostream:600:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Tp> std::basic_ostream<_CharT
, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&)
d:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/ostream:600:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
t.cpp:45:12: note:   'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' is not derived from 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>'
```

Comment: Why did you define `<<` to mean `+=` for strings? Other than to confuse anyone who reads any of your code? What is the purpose? _Strings are not streams._

Comment: Personally, I try adding paranthesis in a case like this. Although I may not understand exactly what's happening.

Comment: Compiles and runs for me with both VC++ 2013 Preview and g++ 4.8.1.

Comment: Are you sure that your definition of the operator is available when you try to use it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I used strings just fro simplicity od example. Actually, there were strings and vectors. 
And you said strings are not streams, so, do you mean the operator<< is allwed for streams only?

Comment: Qt make use of << a lot for more things than streams. I have no personal opinion if its good or bad. But often those functions are redundant.

Comment: @OlegG: No, technically speaking your code is completely valid and allowed, but it's quite different from the traditional use of that operator which can be deemed a problem. Other people need to understand your code too. Defining `operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::vector<T>&)` would be a _good_ example of an operator overload; it's strange to have one that concatenates into a string, though.

Comment: @Gorpik: yes, it is located among other operators which are uesed in code successfully.

Comment: Have you tried exactly the code that you show us? It is OK to change the example as long as it displays the same behaviour as your original code. Otherwise, we are looking for an error that is not here.

Comment: @Gorpik: actually, it is extraction from a large fragment of code but I tried to make extraction carefully after several attempts to fix the error.

Comment: @OlegG Anyway, have you tried to compile exactly what you show us (plus the standard headers, of course)? If this compiles and works correctly, the error is somewhere else and we cannot see it.

Comment: @OlegG You were right to produce a minimal testcase, but unfortunately this one demonstrates that the problem is _not_ inherent to the operator overload. You should have tried it before posting.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You see the real compilation log from real code. Seems, you just unable to say some thing helpful.

Comment: @Gorpik: Yes, I compiled exactly what you see and you see the real log. Moreover, if I change head of operator's description on the following one `std::string & operator<< (std::strig & left, std::string & right){`, then compiler prints the following:`error: declaration of 'operator<<'` as non-function and `error: 'strig' is not a member of 'std'`. This obviously indicates that compiler observes operator's definition.

Comment: @OlegG: But we're not working with real code; we're working with the testcase that you published, and the testcase does not exhibit the problem. Instead of insulting and attacking the experts who are giving their time to help you for free, take a step back, adjust your attitude, then come back and help us to help you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: and what can I say you to help you to help me?

Answer (score 4):

It *does* work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string & operator<< (std::string & left, std::string & right){
    return left += right;
}

int main()
{
    std::string t1("t1"), t2("t2"), t3;
    t3 = t2 << t1;

    std::cout << t3;
}
```

[**Output:** t2t1](http://ideone.com/Gag1Di) [GCC 4.8.1]

The compiler output, as you say yourself, indicates that your operator overload is not even visible. You must not have your declaration in the right place.

This is not really a good idea, anyway: you will simply confuse the heck out of anybody who reads your code. *Strings are not streams.*

Comment: I think because you do not know anything about my code you can't judge about confusion other by it.

Comment: Seems strange that you would need this when you already have operator += for string overloaded which does exactly as you'd expect.

Comment: @paulm: may be it is more strange that you don't know this :)

Comment: @OlegG: I disagree. You need to think about other people; in this case, the vast majority of them, who have _much_ experience in this sort of thing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: thanks for you care about other people and you're right in this but in thsi case strings are used just for simplicity(!). Actial objects are other than strings but behaviour is the same.

Comment: So when I define operator << which sets a strings content to "ALL YOUR BASE ARE BELONG TO US" then that's obvious right?